# É possível definir o número de itens exibidos em uma material table por device?

Tags: react, material-ui, material

Estou fazendo um projeto em React e tenho um componente que faz uma listagem de dados usando a Material Table. Por padrão eu defini para exibir 10 itens por página, porém no mobile fica ruim ter tantos itens, principalmente pelo fato que exibo esses dados dentro de um modal

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';

import MaterialTableCore from 'material-table';
import AddBox from '@material-ui/icons/AddBox';
import ArrowDownward from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowDownward';
import Check from '@material-ui/icons/Check';
import ChevronLeft from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRight from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import Clear from '@material-ui/icons/Clear';
import DeleteOutline from '@material-ui/icons/DeleteOutline';
import Edit from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import FilterList from '@material-ui/icons/FilterList';
import FirstPage from '@material-ui/icons/FirstPage';
import LastPage from '@material-ui/icons/LastPage';
import Remove from '@material-ui/icons/Remove';
import SaveAlt from '@material-ui/icons/SaveAlt';
import Search from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import ViewColumn from '@material-ui/icons/ViewColumn';

const tableIcons = {
  Add: forwardRef((props, ref) => <AddBox {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Check: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Check {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Clear: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Delete: forwardRef((props, ref) => <DeleteOutline {...props} ref={ref} />),
  DetailPanel: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />
  )),
  Edit: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Edit {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Export: forwardRef((props, ref) => <SaveAlt {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Filter: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FilterList {...props} ref={ref} />),
  FirstPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FirstPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
  LastPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <LastPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
  NextPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
  PreviousPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <ChevronLeft {...props} ref={ref} />
  )),
  ResetSearch: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Search: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Search {...props} ref={ref} />),
  SortArrow: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ArrowDownward {...props} ref={ref} />),
  ThirdStateCheck: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Remove {...props} ref={ref} />),
  ViewColumn: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ViewColumn {...props} ref={ref} />),
};

const MaterialTable = (props) => (
  <MaterialTableCore
    {...props}
    icons={tableIcons}
    localization={{
      header: {
        actions: 'Ações',
      },
      body: {
        emptyDataSourceMessage: 'Nenhum registro para exibir',
      },
      toolbar: {
        searchTooltip: 'Pesquisar',
        searchPlaceholder: 'Pesquisar',
      },
      pagination: {
        labelRowsSelect: 'por página',
        labelDisplayedRows: '{from} à {to} de {count}',
        firstTooltip: 'Primeira página',
        previousTooltip: 'Página anterior',
        nextTooltip: 'Próxima página',
        lastTooltip: 'Última página',
      },
    }}
    options={{
      pageSize:10,
      actionsColumnIndex:3
    }}
  />
);

export default MaterialTable;
```

No options eu setei no pagSize para exibir 10 itens por página, mas gostaria de saber se tem como fazer um condicional por device para exibir menos itens. Na imagem a seguir da pra ver que o modal fica cortando os itens do Material Table e se reduzir pra 5 itens por página no mobile ficaria correto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a função a seguir dentro do componente. Antes, verifique se ela funciona do jeito que você espera, testando no Firefox/Chrome/etc no modo responsivo do devTools (ctrl + shift + M). No meu caso, o snippet printa que é mobile se eu usá-lo.

```js
function isMobile() {
    let mql = window.matchMedia('only screen and (max-width: 760px)');
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera|Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && mql.matches ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(isMobile() ? 'parece ser mobile' : 'não parece ser mobile')
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado!